# Add a query string to anchor link from query embedded in current URL

Tags: javascript, wordpress, hyperlink, anchor, query-string

how do I dynamically add a "?q='query'" (where 'query' is the query string from a search box and is embedded in the the current page URL example.com/search/?='query') to an anchor link on the page?

An example of this can be found on the website: https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=test

Here the page include links with the '?q=test' query added to them (e.g. https://www.ecosia.org/images?q=test)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

This will append the querystring from the page URL onto every link on the page.

```
var qs =window.location.search; 
$('a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href')
    $(this).attr('href',href+qs)
})
```